# Powershell how to get "Start In" information for process started by shortcut

Tags: windows, powershell, shortcut-file

I have a process that was started with a desktop shortcut.
The desktop shortcut has information in the "Start In" field.
I would like to get the "Start In" information for the process.
Is this possible?  How would I do it using Powershell?

I have looked at the properties returned by Get-Process and Get-WMIObject win32_process
but I cannot seem to find where I can find the "Start in" information.  TIA

**Update**

The reason I need this information is that I have a couple of programs ran by python.  I have shortcuts setup to start these.  The shortcut target is:

```
python.exe my_script.py
```

However, there are a couple of versions of my_script.py on the computer, none of which are on the PATH.  I set the "Start in" property of shortcut to control which version of my_script.py is executed.

I realize there are other ways to change so that I could tell which script version is running, however I'm trying to not make changes to the existing setup, and write a powershell script that could get this information.

Comment: There isn't really any way for the process object to know this. All that the start in field does is to set the initial working directory. The process can change the working directory at will and there is no need for it to ever know which working directory it started in. This may be an XY problem situation (http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Why exactly do you feel that you need to do this?

Comment: @EBGreen, thanks for the reply, please see the Update for more information.

Comment: I understand your desire to maintain the status quo, but I'm not sure that what you want to do is possible. Why exactly do you need to know which version is running?

Comment: @EBGreen, thanks for the info.  I am taking a snapshot of the system for post-analysis.  I'm doing this for a number of computers and looking for any odd configurations so it can be corrected.

Comment: BTW, "its not possible" is a valid answer in this situation :-)  Will give me a reason to request changes to the setup.

Answer (score 0):

If your desktop shortcut has a predictable file name, say shortcut.lnk, then maybe this helps?

```
$lnkPath = get-childItem .\shortcut.lnk | select -expand fullname
$wsh = New-Object -COM WScript.Shell
$wsh.CreateShortcut($lnkPath).workingDirectory
```

Comment: thanks for the info.  I am more interested in trying to find which shortcut was clicked (i.e. which version of the script was ran).  But I'll keep this in mind in the future when working with shortcuts.